# Zooming a dynamic layout in android

Tags: android

I have an image view placed inside a linear layout in layout XML. I like to add few buttons on the image at run time. On clicking the button I need to perform some actions.I want to zoom the layout(along with static image and dynamic buttons). Even at zoomed state the button click is to be sensed. Is there anyway to do it? Do I need a custom layout here? Any pointers on custom layouts and zoom is appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a relative layout which has the imageView inside it to fill it all , while the zooming buttons are also there but are only attached to the bottom (for example) .